# list of stings into list of integers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to convert multiple columns where each row contains a list of strings to rows containing lists of integers?

From this state

```
index    column_1     column_2    column_3    column_4  column_5   column_6
0      ['1','1']     ['7','6']    ['1','3']      7        2       ['5','1']
```

To this state

```
index column_1     column_2    column_3    column_4  column_5  column_6
0      [1,1]       [7 , 6 ]    [ 1 , 3 ]       7        2       [5 , 1]
```

I have tried many solutions the only one that worked was the one below **but** for a single column

```
df['column_1'].map(lambda a: map(int, a))
```

Comment: Have you attempted a solution, or are you expecting somebody else to do the work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that converts that dataframe to a 2D list, performs the necessary conversion to integers, and converts back to dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':[['1','1']], 'column_2':[['7','6']], 'column_3':[['1','3']],
                   'column_4':[7], 'column_5':[2], 'column_6':[['5','1']]})

cols = df.columns.array
lst = df.to_numpy().tolist()
for row in lst:
    for col in row:
        if type(col) == list:
            for i, numstring in enumerate(col):
                col[i] = int(numstring)

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns= cols)
print(df)

#output:
  column_1 column_2 column_3  column_4  column_5 column_6
0   [1, 1]   [7, 6]   [1, 3]         7         2   [5, 1]
```